# Trigger in Postgres to update a column in main table with minimum value from other tables

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.6

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE main (sno int, ID varchar, A int);
CREATE TABLE aux_1 (ID varchar, b int);
CREATE TABLE aux_2 (ID varchar, c int);
```

**Objective:** To ensure that values in column A of main table = LEAST(Value in column b of aux_1 table Vs. Value in column c of aux_2 table). Graphical illustration is here - [Link](http://dropbox.com/s/hv0dvsn2dm2nwx1/Example.png?dl=0)

**My attempt:** I created the following function called min_compare() to accomplish auto-update of main table

```
DECLARE
id_temp VARCHAR;
b_temp INTEGER;
c_temp INTEGER;
min_value INTEGER;

BEGIN
FOR r IN 1 .. 100
LOOP
SELECT INTO id_temp main."ID" FROM main WHERE sno = r;
SELECT INTO b_temp aux_1.b FROM aux_1 WHERE aux_1."ID" = id_temp;
SELECT INTO c_temp aux_2.c FROM aux_2 WHERE aux_2."ID" = id_temp;

IF b_temp > c_temp THEN min_price := c_temp;
ELSE min_price := b_temp;
RETURN min_price;
END IF;
UPDATE main SET "a" = min_price WHERE "ID" = id_temp;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Trigger for table aux_1

```
CREATE TRIGGER min_value AFTER UPDATE ON aux_1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE min_compare();
```

Trigger for table aux_2

```
CREATE TRIGGER min_value AFTER UPDATE ON aux_2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE min_compare();
```

**Problem**: When I update column b of table aux_1 and/or column c of table aux_2, the corresponding value in column A of main table doesn't update.

I am totally a newbie to postgresql and plpgsql. Pardon me if this is a totally stupid question but I tried to search all over to reach up till this stage and now I am totally stuck. Please help.

Comment: can you clarify this statement a bit: "To ensure that values in column A of main table = LEAST(Value in column b of aux_1 table Vs. Value in column c of aux_2 table)" perhaps give an example

Comment: If you are sure there will be only non-NULL values in aux_1 and aux_2 for all values of ID, you can replace your code with one select - SELECT LEAST(p.b,q.c) from aux_1 as p join  aux_2 as q on p.id = q.id join main as s on p.id = s.id and s.sno = r. If there can be multiple records in the aux tables, use MIN function also.

Comment: @e4c5 Here is the link for an image that has an example. I don't have reputation to post images so could not post it here. Please bear with me on this. Thanks - https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv0dvsn2dm2nwx1/Example.png?dl=0

Comment: @Jayadevan How would a select query update a column in table? Please refer to the link in previous comment to see example of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I was saying your 3 select queries can be replaced by one select. Yes, select query can be used to update a column too. Look at the example UPDATE accounts SET (contact_last_name, contact_first_name) =
    (SELECT last_name, first_name FROM salesmen
     WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id);  at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

Comment: @Jayadevan Thanks for sharing this. :)